# Continuing from the point where I left

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Just another question: When I start my application on a device (be it android or ios), use it for a while, then minimize it and then activate it, the app starts from the beginning and not continues from where I minimized it. How can I solve this issue?

best to all
babür

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is- When you start your application than your system checks app's ManifestFile to get An activity whose Intent-filter action and category is set to "android.intent.action.MAIN" and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" .

This activity is your app's launcher(first) activity.

When you starts your app "Android system" adds this activity in your Activity stack.As you start some other activity that one also add to the top of Activity stack.

On finish an activity it will removed from Activity stack.

whenever you start your app "Android system" traces Activity stack to get top activity and start your application from that one.

If it found Activity stack empty the system starts your app with your app's launcher Activity.

In your case you finishes all activities.Thus your Activity stack becomes empty and it start you app with launcher Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you background an app in iOS, it may just be running in the background, or the system may terminate it if it needs the memory for other apps.  If you are terminated, when you come back to the app, it will be relaunched and seem as if you have "started from the beginning".

To get around this, you write code that will save your app's state when you are going into the background.  When you are launched, you then restore your state based on the information you saved.  iOS does provide some mechanisms to help you with this.

Other times, when the app comes back from the background, without having been terminated, then the app doesn't need to do anything and just continues on, where the user left off.